# why javascript Delete backslash(\) when Using Onclick method for File Addresses

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, onclick, wwwroot

Why Javascript Methods like (javascript onclick, and Onchange) Getting File Addresses like this ( FilesItem38069707322680384-5832364197407734490_121.jpg ) instead of correct way like this(Files\Item\638069707322680384-5832364197407734490_121.jpg)

i expecting for javascript Methods to Send The File Address on the correct way with backslash,
what should i do for javascript method to do not delet backslash for file address

Comment: Your title says `/` (forward slash) but the question shows `\ ` (backslash). Please clarify and show a [mre].

Comment: backslash is the escape character in string literals. You need to double it to enter a literal backslash.

Comment: But backslashes shouldn't be used in URLs, they use forward slashes.